# How to change the scrollable area of UITableView?

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiscrollview

I think it'd be a good start to take a look at the wireframe I'm implementing: https://i.stack.imgur.com/naB60.jpg

So this is a special table view, and the background image is much bigger than the table area. And what I want is to have the background scrollable and have the table stick to a specific position on the background, and the table moves together with the background.

**EDIT**: Besides, this position may change over some time.

I found it hard to do by extending UITableView since I didn't find the way to change the scrollable area and actually I didn't find how to access the view containing all the rows so I don't know how to position it.

Currently I'm doing this with a UITableView in a UIScrollView but I think that's a waste since UITableView is already a UIScrollView itself.

So anyone knows it's possible to change the scrollable area to the whole background and how to access the rows' container? Or it's not possible? If it's not possible it'd be easier to just make a simple list view by myself and get rid of UITableView I think.

Thanks!

Pine

Comment: What's going to be above and below it? Can you achieve what you want by adding large header and footer views to the table?

Comment: @jrturton the reason it may not work is the table's position relative to the background may change over time, in order to do that I may need to use 2 extra views and change those 2 views' frames. There could be different kinds of color shapes above or below the table, inside of the background view.